# replacing all instances on a page - javascript

Tags: jquery, replace

Hi I would like to replace all href and action attributes on a page with href="#" and action="#".  Could someone point out where i am going wrong;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var contents = $("body").html();
contents.replace( /href=[\"'][^'\"]*[\"']/g, 'href="#"' );
contents.replace( /action=[\"'][^'\"]*[\"']/g, 'action="#"' );
});
```

I would also like to do this without the use of jQuery but not sure how.

Comment: Are you trying to do this dynamically or is this just a one-time mass edit of a page?

Comment: what it is is I have made a CMS. When it comes to previewing pages before edit, I dont want the user to be able click on a link and the temp page is randomly generated and the links would go no where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you try something like :

```
$('a').attr('href','#');
$('form').attr('action','#');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a, area, form").each(function(){
        if (typeof $(this).attr("href") != 'undefined') {
            $(this).attr("href", "#");
        }else if(typeof $(this).attr("action") != 'undefined') {
            $(this).attr("action", "#");
        }
    });
});
```

I added a tick to Soufiane Hassou answer as I found the answer via his comment, thanks